Weighing Coins Problem
There are $20$ seemingly identical coins, ordered in row. One of them weighs $9$ grams, next to it, to the right, there is another one that weighs $11$ grams. The other $18$ coins weigh $10$ grams each. Describe how can we determine the $11$-gram coin by weighing at most $3$ times in a pan balance.
NOTE: A pan balance only informs whether the left plate weighs more, the same, or less
than the right plate.
I know that the problem for $n$ times is solvable for at most $3^n$ coins, when we have just one different coin. The truth is that for two different coins, when their weighs cancel out, the problem seems imposible. To be honest, I have no clue on how to turn the problem into math.

I suggest:  if $3$ weighings is too hard, try to do it in $4$, or $5$ or whatever.  It's clearly possible to do it with a bunch of weighings...it only takes a few pairs to find two that match, so then you have a $10$ for sure and can just do one on one to get everything.  Now try to be more efficient about it.  That said, $3$ does seem awfully small.

here is a duplicate which appears to claim that $6$ weighings is minimal  I haven't checked the details.

Thank you. I skipped a detail that I did not take into account that was very important. I'll edit the post.

@lulu The 6-weighings solution finds both coins. With 3 weighings, we cannot possibly hope to achieve that, but we might still be able to find one coin.

@MishaLavrov  Ah, good point.  I missed that we only wanted one of them.  $3$ still seems low though.

Sorry for before. The problem assures that the two different coins are next to each other, in a row.

They're next to each other, so just take the coins in the odd positions - there is only one bad coin in this group, so you've reduced to the case with 10 coins, one of which is either heavier or lighter. Try both finding this coin, as well as the direction of anomaly in 3 weightings - this is enough because if the anomaly is heavy, you'd already be done, and if light, then pick the one to the right originally.

@stochasticboy321  Good idea.

This is a spoiler, I suppose, but a hint: for the 10 coin problem, one strategy begins with the weightings (123) against (456) and (123) against (789).

Look up the $12$ coins.  You can find the odd one out among $12$ in $3$ weighings and determine if it is heavy or light.  Here you only have $10$ coins.

@lulu, Since in this case there is a constraint on the location it is not as in the link you supplied.

@Royi  Indeed, the OP drastically modified the problem from their original version.

The pan balance is the encoder. Namely it is a ternary encoder.
To know how many weights are needed, you need to calculate the number of combinations possible.
If you ignore the knowledge about the coins being next to each other, which reduce the number of combinations, you need to think about how many ways you can order 2 different coins within 20 coins:
$$ 2!  \binom{20}{2} = 380 $$
It means it will require $\lceil \log_{3} \left( 300 \right) \rceil = 6$.
Now, given their relative order, think about the number of such combinations.
Since they are one next to each other, to the one on the right there are 19 places to be at.
Hence the actual number is $\lceil \log_{3} \left( 19 \right) \rceil = 3$.
